# Function returning undefined from a promise

Tags: javascript, function

I'm trying to make a function that returns an xkcd password like this: `bat-ship-eight-loophole`. The library can be found here: https://github.com/fardog/node-xkcd-password

Here is my code:

```
var xkcdPassword = require('xkcd-password')
var pw = new xkcdPassword()

var options = {
  numWords: 4,
  minLength: 5,
  maxLength: 8
}

// or, with promises
function generateCode() {
    pw.generate(options).then(function (result) {
        return "hello"
    })
}

console.log(generateCode())
```

I don't think my issue has anything to do with the library though

Comment: `return pw.generate(options) ...` you need to return something to have something returned

Comment: @JaromandaX I am; `return "hello"`

Comment: I think you're missing a return statement `return pw.generate()`to receveive the result of the promise

Comment: that's not a return from `generateCode` it's a return from the .then callback

Comment: @ÉricRoberge - `the result of the promise` - no, that would return a promise ... the result is only available in .then

Comment: as @JaromandaX pointed out you are not explicitly `return`ing from `generateCode` - therefore it will return `undefined`. Also, returning anything other than a promise there is not really useful. You can't get a synchronous return value from asynchronous code. Whatever logic you want to do should happen in the callback. There is an explicit example of this in the link you posted - an example you altered for no discernible reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Promises are a way to represent asynchronous operations which potentially haven't completed yet. In order to get the output, you have to make your function return the promise, and use `then` to add a callback function that takes the output.

```
function generateCode() {
    return pw.generate(options);
}

generateCode().then(function(code) {
    console.log(code);
});

// pw.generate(options).then(console.log); // also works in this case
```

Comment: Ok thanks! I'll try that. I edited your question to remove the extra return statement.

Comment: I rejected your edit because it changed what the code did. What do you want to be logged?

Comment: I want a function that returns an xkcd password. Then I want to call the function and log the password to the console

Comment: Ok thanks! I ended up just doing this though: `pw.generate(options).then((password) => {
    console.log(password.join("-"));
})`. I'd misunderstood how to use promises!